# vue3 setting css styles from vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Within vue3 is it possible to bind a value from the vuex store to a component style? for example, i have a color saved within the store as backgroundColor and would like to do something like below:

Store:

```
store = {
    state: {
        branding: {
            color: '#f00'
        }
    }
}
```

component script

```
export default {
    name: 'component',
    components: {
        Header,
        Footer
    },
    branding() {
        return this.$store.state.branding.color;
    },
}
```

component style

```
.page{
    background-color: v-bind(branding.colour);
}
```

i have seen an example of this working:

```
export default {
    name: 'component',
    components: {
        Header,
        Footer
    },
    data(){
        return {
            color: '#f00'
        }
    },
} 


.page{
    background-color: v-bind(colour);
}
```

but i need to grab the data from the store. im pretty new to vue but not too sure on how to resolve this.

Comment: What you tried was close, but you need to match the name of the computed: in your case: `v-bind(branding)`. And remember you can always use the good old `v-bind:style`, directly in template: `<div :style="{ backgroundImage: branding }" />`

Comment: Oops! I meant `{ backgroundColor: branding }`.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 6 April 2022

Apparently I was wrong and in Vue 3 it is possible to use `v-bind` inside CSS as shown in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css). So it should be possible to use Vuex getter or local computed property.

---

<s>You can not access JavaScript variables from CSS</s>. You should either set inline style to your HTML tag(s) or define the color as CSS variable and **then** access it from other CSS rules.

```html
<template>
  <div :style="{backgroundColor: brandingColor}">test</div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  computed:
  {
    brandingColor()
    {
      return this.$store.state.branding.color;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

OR

```js
// main.js

new Vue({
  created()
  {
    const style = document.documentElement.style;
    const theme = this.$store.state.branding;
    for (const key in theme)
    {
      style.setProperty('--branding-' + key, theme[key]);
    }
  }
});
```

MyComponent.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="page">text</div>
</template>

<style>
.page
{
  background-color: var(--branding-color);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was trying to do this with vue3, https://learnvue.co/2021/05/how-to-use-vue-css-variables-reactive-styles-rfc/#how-can-we-use-sfc-styles and I had it working as the SFC Example but it wasn’t pulling from the store! I think I like this way better! I’ll give it a go! Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is `false`. You can reference any instance props/data/computed in CSS,  with `v-bind(name)`. See [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8aDE+e3sgY29sb3IgfX08L2gxPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblxuPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmNvbnN0IGNvbG9yID0gJyNmNTAnXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjxzdHlsZT5cbiAgaDEgeyBjb2xvcjogdi1iaW5kKGNvbG9yKTsgfVxuPC9zdHlsZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59In0=). It also works with Options API.